# I'm trying to integrate PayPal Payment with Contact Form 7 in WordPress, and my Redirect isn't working

Tags: wordpress, forms, paypal, contact-form-7

I'm working on a Charity site where we want to accept membership payments and donations via paypal.

I am having a problem with Contact Form 7 and redirection to PayPal with a variable payment amount.  I'm really hoping that someone can assist or shed some insight on this problem for me.

I read [This Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/get-values-from-contact-form-7-wp-plugin), which made it sound quite easy but, while my email is being sent, the form isn't redirecting to PayPal, in fact it's not doing anything at all, not even giving me the "thank you your form has been submitted" notice.

my form has this line:   £[text* AmountPaying 6/ id:PayingThis]

And under "Additional Settings"  I have inserted this:

```
<script>
    function my_redirect() {
        var price = document.getElementById("PayingThis").value;
        var url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=#####&currency_code=GBP&amount="+price+"&return=http://www.example.org/join-or-renew-your-membership-online/";
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
on_sent_ok: "my_redirect();"
```

does anybody have any experience with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments !

With some help troubleshooting from a friend I have figured out how to make this happen with contactForm7 - in fact, I believe you could extend this solution, and submit a lot of dynamic information directly to PayPalmy problem.

This is what I did - and it's essentially the same as [this guy does here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/get-values-from-contact-form-7-wp-plugin)

BUT,  instead of putting that code in the  "ADDITIONAL SETTINGS" Area of the CF7 Form page -  I added this:

```
<script>
    function my_redirect() {
     var price = document.getElementById("PayingThis").value;
     var url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=#######&currency_code=GBP&amount="+price+"&return=http://www.example.org/join-or-renew-your-membership-online/";
     window.location = url;  
    }
</script>
```

up at the top, with the rest of the Form building html and tags, just before the code for the form itself: 
    Your Name (required): [text* your-name]

etc.

and then in the Additional settings box.. I only called the function
    on_sent_ok: "my_redirect();"

and it worked! it takes the value the user enters in the "How much do you want to give us" box, and submits it to paypal

I hope others can benefit from this

thanks again for taking the time to view and help

-5tratus

Comment: tx for sharing. Question have you modified your solution in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Alex,  nope..    This is still my solution.. but I've had to revert to an older version of CF7  when I upgraded.. just at the same time as the last wordpress upgrade went through.. this solution stopped working.   When I reverted to the previous version of CF7.. it started again.   there's been an update since.. but I don't dare update it again, in case it's still broken :-/

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 is a great plugin but creating a form for PayPal gets a little tricky. Gravity Forms would be a great options but you would need the developers license that cost $200.

My recommendation is to look up the PayPal form API and create the form yourself, from scratch and integrate it OR you should have a look at the **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin, and the **PayPal Field Add-on** for Advanced Custom Fields! It's all free.

It enables you to set a form on any post/page/etc with a paypal button. All you have to do is add the `<?php the_field('NAME_OF_YOUR_FIELD'); ?>` to your template, wherever you want to display it.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-paypal-field/

Comment: Hi Iammikerodriguez,  Thanks for the comments, they're really appreciated,  Unfortunately, this is a pro-bonno job for a charity, and i'm just a buddhist nun -  so $200 for Gravity Forms is just out of the question for us. 
However,  I did find a solution!! And I'll post it as an answer here!  - -5trat

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 5tratus. Works.

An old support thread (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-paypal-integration-1) was getting as far as redirecting to PayPal, but then PayPal was giving an "Page Not Found" "You have requested an outdated version of PayPal" message.

I didn't need price or any extra variables, so I cleaned it up to just redirect to the product page. Here's what I used and it works:

```
<script>
function my_redirect() {
 var url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=[PUT YOUR BUTTON ID HERE]";
 window.location = url;  
}</script>
```

As 5tratus says, put the above code in at the bottom of the form code itself, then put

```
on_sent_ok: "my_redirect();"
```

in the "additional settings" part.

**Refer this useful plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-paypal-extension/**